# Can't set the adapter of a Spinner into a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I got this error while trying to fill the items of a snipper with the elements of an array.

This is the error I have:

> 02-06 21:00:58.519 7493-7493/com.dogsupdate.dogsupdate E/dalvikvm:
>   Could not find class 'android.widget.ThemedSpinnerAdapter', referenced
>   from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter.

```
String[] lang = {"es","en"};

final View layout=inflater.inflate(
    R.layout.fragment_fragment_settings, container, false);

Spinner lang = (Spinner) layout.findViewById(R.id.setLang);

lang.setAdapter(
  new ArrayAdapter<String>(
     getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
     android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item , 
     idiomas));

return inflater.inflate(
  R.layout.fragment_fragment_settings, container, false);
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change last line to `return layout;`

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is getting `layout` from `LayoutInflater`

```
final View layout=inflater.inflate(
R.layout.fragment_fragment_settings, container, false);
```

Finding the `Spinner` from the `layout`

```
Spinner lang = (Spinner) layout.findViewById(R.id.setLang);
```

Setting `ArrayAdapter` to `Spinner`

```
lang.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item ,  idiomas));
```

and returning the new layout from inflating again

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_settings, container, false);
```

so change the return statement by

```
return layout;
```

and it'll work perfectly...